# Loop through an array (+100 values)

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
$my_array = array("1", "2", "3", "4");
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
1 vs 2
3 vs 4
```

Because the length of my array is only 4 it was easy for me to do this:

```
echo $my_array[0]." vs ".$my_array[1];
echo "<br>";
echo $my_array[2]." vs ".$my_array[3];
```

But how can I achieve this if my array has more than 100 values? I also want to account for odd numbers of array elements.

Comment: foreach loop, odd\even pairs (watch for 0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "for" loop, with an increment of two for every loop :

```
$len = count($my_array);
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i=$i+2) {
    echo $my_array[$i]." vs ".$my_array[$i+1]."<br/>;
}
```

If you're not sure your array always contains an even number of indexes, you can add a condition in order to ignore the last case if there is no more pair to do.

```
$len = count($my_array);
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i=$i+2) {
    if($i !== $len-1) {
        echo $my_array[$i]." vs ".$my_array[$i+1]."<br/>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, `for` loop is the obvious answer, but there are more interesting ones ;)

```
$my_array = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
$new_array = array_map(
    function($v) {return isset($v[1]) ? "$v[0] vs $v[1]<br/>" : null; },
    array_chunk($my_array, 2)
);
print_r($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 vs 2<br/>
    [1] => 3 vs 4<br/>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop to loop through the array.

```
$my_array = array("1", "2", "3", "4","5","6");
for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($my_array); $x = $x+2) {
    echo $my_array[0+$x]." vs ".$my_array[1+$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```